# Run a SQL query in Excel using a date in the workbook

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am using an SQL query to pull data. I have to change the @StartDate and @endDate within the query.

Is there a way to have the query pull the dates from the Excel spreadsheet?

The query: [Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxfw4.png)

The spreadsheet has an area to input the dates (ignore the formatting): [Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z6X8.png)

Comment: The query in your screenshot, is that already incorporated into the Excel spreadsheet as a Query? Or are you running it via SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1422451)

Comment: That particular reference was in SQL Management studio, but I do have it incorporated in the spreadsheet I am working with.

Comment: Your SQL shown in the screenshot would not run the syntax is incorrect. Here is an example of how to `FORMAT` dates for T-SQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

Simply build a parameterized query via ADO where you pass your spreadsheet date values into query to return needed results.

**SQL** *(save query as .sql file containing a single `SELECT` replacing all @vars with qmarks, `?`)*

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM...
WHERE ...
```

**VBA** *(Adjust paths and worksheet names and ranges)*

```vb
Sub GetQuery()
On Error Goto ErrHandler
    ' SET REFERENCE TO Microsoft ActiveX Data Object #.# Library
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date
 
    ' BUILD SQL FROM FILE
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        strSQL = .OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\my\SQL\Query.sql", 1).readall
    End With

    ' RETRIEVE DATES (ADJUST TO ACTUALS)
    startDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A1")
    endDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A2")

    ' OPEN DB CONNECTION (ADJUST TO ACTUALS)
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};" _
          & "Server=localhost;" _
          & "Database=myDatabase;" _
          & "Trusted_Connection=yes"

    ' DEFINE COMMAND OBJECT
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = strSQL
    
        ' BIND DATE PARAMETERS BY POSITION FOR ? IN SQL
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("dtparam1", adDate, adParamInput, , startDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("dtparam2", adDate, adParamInput, , startDate)

        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("dtparam3", adDate, adParamInput, , endDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("dtparam4", adDate, adParamInput, , endDate)

        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("dtparam5", adDate, adParamInput, , startDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("dtparam6", adDate, adParamInput, , endDate)

        ' BIND OUTPUT TO RECORDSET
        Set rs = .Execute
    End With

   ' SAVE DATA TO WORKSHEET
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyResults")
         ' HEADERS
         For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count
             .Cells(1, i +1) = rs.Fields(i).Name
         Next i

         '  DATA ROWS
         .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

    rs.Close

ExitHandler:
    Set cmd = Nothing: Set rs = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```